# Locating boundary layers for pertubation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, perturbation-theory

Consider the BVP:

$\epsilon \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(x^2-2)y=-1
\\ \text{where} -1<x<1 \;\text{and} \; y(-1)=y(1)=0, \; 0<\epsilon<<1$

**I am trying to show the existence of a boundary layer at $x=-1$ and $x=1$**, but am stuck. So far I have shown that the solution $y(x)$ is symmetric, so this should simplify matters to just proving $x=1$ or $x=-1$ is a boundary layer. What is a good way to approach this?

Comment: Well, since the outer solution that abel showed (when $\epsilon=0$) does not satisfy the boundary conditions, you need inner solutions at each boundary so that you can satisfy them. That's how you identify where a boundary layer is. Sometimes your outer solution can be made to match one but not both boundary conditions. Then you have either a boundary layer at one boundary, or an internal boundary layer, and these can be more difficult to locate.

Comment: If you still have your notes available, could you check the operation signs, as is there are no boundary layers as the inner solution oscillates without converging. $ϵy''+(x^2-2)y=-1$ has boundary layers with the inner equation $Y''-Y=0$.

Answer (score 0):

i will give it a try. you get the  outer solution by setting $\epsilon = 0.$ so you get $$y_{outer} = \frac1{x^2 - 2}$$ to find the solution valid in a boundary layer near $x = 1,$ you define a stretched variable $$\xi = (x-1)/\sqrt \epsilon, x = \sqrt \epsilon \xi + 1, \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{d^2y}{d\xi^2}$$
so the differential equation becomes 
$$\frac{d^2y}{d\xi^2}-\left((\sqrt \epsilon\xi + 1)^2 - 2\right)y=-1 $$ at the leading order we get $$ \frac{d^2y}{d\xi^2}+y=-1,\,y(0) = 0. $$ so the inner solution is 
$$y_{inner}(\xi) = -1 + \cos \xi = -1 + \cos\left(\frac{x-1}{\sqrt \epsilon} \right)$$

i hope you can take it from here.